# Requiring certain patterns for fields being populated in a Java builder

Tags: java, spring

```
class Builder {
  private Foo myItem = new Foo();

  public Builder field1(Bar val) {
    myItem.setField1(val);
    return this;  
  }

  public Builder field2(Baz val) {
    myItem.setField2(val);
    return this;  
  }

  public Builder field3(Gaz val) {
    myItem.setField3(val);
    return this;  
  }

  public Foo build() {
    return myItem;
  }

}
```

Say for my class above I want all fields, or field1 and field 2 together or only field3 populated.

```
public Foo build() throws Exception {
  if ((myItem.getField1() == null || myItem.getField2() == null) && myItem.getField3() == null) {    
    throw new Exception();
  }
  return myItem;
}
```

This accomplishes the goal although in a very verbose and hard to understand way. What is a better approach to accomplish the same goal: make patterns of fields mandatory?

Comment: If you have parameters that *should* go together, the easiest approach would be to have a constructor which accepts the pairs that should go together.

Comment: just a comment, not an answer, you shouldn't add `throws IllegalStateException` in your method signature, it is a runtime exception. Also you return `myItem`, not `myItem()`

Comment: @Bentaye edited to make it less sloppy

Comment: @npinti the main reason one would use a builder is dealing with a large number of fields without using constructors with 10 parameters in the signature or having a dozen constructors to accommodate each case

Comment: @VictorS I mean, you should throw the exception, ie : `throw new IllegalStateException();` but the signature should not have a throws, ie: `public Object build() {` but anyways, this is not related to your question

Comment: I think this question could better be placed in CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @TobiasOtto how so? This is example code and the question is on general practices

Comment: I have some difficulties with your sample code, because it has no meaning for me. For example field1, field2 and field2 are of type Object, but the result of the builder is of type Object, too.  
This does not compile and does not make sense.  
You want to have an advice to make your code better and not *very verbose and hard to understand*. So how should one give you a good advice on this basis?

Comment: @TobiasOtto it is representational of course it will not compile. Please let me know if my edit makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. You should seperate the fields 1,2 and 3 in two seperate classes.

When you say that the object has either field1 and field2 OR field3, than you have two different classes.

Comment: My bad, forgot the part where I mention all 3 are also populated

Answer (score 0):

What about this idea: Have two builders inheriting from a Builder class ?

The parent class delegates field1 and field2 to one implementation, and field3 to another.

Here is the code.

```
public class Builder {

    protected Object myItem = new Object();

    private Field12Builder field12Builder = new Field12Builder(myItem);
    private Field3Builder field3Builder = new Field3Builder(myItem);

    public Builder field1(Object val) throws Exception {
        return field12Builder.field1(val);
    }

    public Builder field2(Object val) throws Exception {
        return field12Builder.field2(val);
    }

    public Builder field3(Object val) throws Exception {
        return field3Builder.field3(val);
    }

    public Object build() throws Exception {
        return myItem;
    }
}


public class Field12Builder extends Builder {

    public Field12Builder(Object myItem) {
        this.myItem = myItem;
    }

    public Builder field1(Object val) {
        myItem.setField1(val);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder field2(Object val) {
        myItem.setField2(val);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder field3(Object val) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Cannot have field3 if field1 or field2 is valorized.");
    }

    public Object build() throws Exception {
        if (myItem.getField1() == null || myItem.getField2() == null) {
            throw new Exception("field1 and field2 must be both valorized.");
        }
        return super.build();
    }
}



public class Field3Builder extends Builder {

    public Field3Builder(Object myItem) {
        this.myItem = myItem;
    }

    public Builder field1(Object val) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Cannot have field1 if field3 is valorized.");
    }

    public Builder field2(Object val) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Cannot have field2 if field3 is valorized.");
    }

    public Builder field3(Object val) {
        myItem.setField3(val);
        return this;
    }

    public Object build() throws Exception {
        return super.build();
    }
}
```